# Selenium WebDriver - no such element: Unable to locate element

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a problem with simple click on button. It's button is CSS.

```
<div id="rightBtn">
<input type="submit" class="mainButton" id="dodajTrenera" value="Dodaj" name="dodaj_trenera">
</div>
```

I would like to perform click action and I use this code:

```
WebElement addTrainer = driver.findElement(By.name("dodaj_trenera"));
    addTrainer.click();
```

I get error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to     locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"dodaj_trenera"}
```

Why I get this error? It should work perfect. 
This button is located at the bottom of web. Maybe I should scroll page down?

Comment: Can you check if the element is inside an iframe or not? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Most commonly such error is a synchronization issue: try to wait for element to be present and clickable before clicking on it, like this:

```
WebElement addTrainer = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.name("dodaj_trenera")));
addTrainer.click();
```

Of course the time you wait can be changed from 10 to whatever makes sense for your page.

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("dodaj_trenera"));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Comment: A code block alone does not provide a good answer. Please add explanations (why it solve the issue, where was the mistake, etc...)